# Change to a new Oracle JDBC driver?

Tags: oracle, jdbc, driver

We are using the Oracle JDBC driver version 9.0.2.0.0 and are having some trouble concerning saving CLOBs to the database. (method `clob.setCharacterStream(0);` throws an `UnsupportedFeatureSqlException`. I think this is because of the old version...

Is it save to switch to the newest 10g driver? (We are using a database of version 10). Or could that cause any problems in our existing queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using version 10 of the DB, I'd definitely use the 10g JDBC drivers.  In fact, and ISTBC, but I think that using 9 JDBC drivers against a 10 DB would be considered unsupported by Oracle.

I don't recall having any issues when we shifted (long time ago now!) but of course you'll have to test.