# Query of queries error with CF_SQL_CLOB: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: setCharacterStream()

Tags: mysql, coldfusion

I'm getting an error that I can't seem to shake. I've made hundreds of query of queries and can't seem to get this one working.

Main query:

```
<cfquery name="SpifCheck" datasource="MILESTONEBMDB">
  SELECT *
  FROM SPIF_list
</cfquery>
```

Loop with query of queries:

```
<cfloop query="orderLineItems">
  <cfquery name="SpifGrabber" dbtype="query">
    SELECT *
    FROM SpifCheck
    WHERE SKUprimary = <cfqueryparam value="#orderLineItems.qProdSku#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_clob" maxlength="255">
  </cfquery>
</cfloop>
```

Which is now throwing this error [image: Error java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: setCharacterStream()]

Comment: Is the datatype for `orderLineItems.qProdSku` really a clob?

Comment: that normall works for me universally, however in this instance he demanded cf_sql_varchar

Comment: Laziness has it's place in programming, but this isn't it.  Specify correct datatypes when using query parameters.

Comment: This bug might be related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8911120/change-to-a-new-oracle-jdbc-driver

Comment: Do not follow the old Dreamweaver query wizard pattern which used cf_sql_clob for *everything* ;-) The cfsqltypes are not just arbitrary names. They determine how values are evaluated and [using the wrong type could produce the wrong results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27049918/coldfusion-parameterizing-a-query/27066113#27066113). Always use the correct type for the underlying column. Side note - querying within a loop usually scales poorly. Consider using JOIN's instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Corrected the issue, for some reason it really didn't like `cf_sql_clob`, changed it to `cf_sql_varchar` and woks perfectly now